# Adding my own UEFI application\driver to the UEFI (VMware)

Tags: driver, vmware, bios, efi, uefi

I have a virtual machine (Windows7x64) that loads from uefi.

Can I add a UEFI application\driver that I've created to the UEFI, in order for it to load it on boot time?

Also, can I change the order which DXE\UEFI driver's are loaded?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot insert your drivers/applications during boot, nor can you change the execution order of the existing drivers without rebuilding the UEFI BIOS. It is also not possible to replace the UEFI BIOS in VMWare with your own image. You can cause VMWare to boot to UEFI Shell and then manually load any UEFI drivers/applications from Shell.

Answer (score 0):

We can create UEFI driver and load also, create and launch UEFI application.

For more info you can refer EDK2 forum, UDK package version of Simulator project to develop new UEFI based DXE, PEI, etc, driver and UEFI shell applications.

Comment: Please add the required steps and source links. [This](https://www.bit-tech.net/news/tech/software/canonical-pulls-ubuntu-1710-over-uefi-corruption-issue/1/) might also be interesting.

Comment: To modify order of existing DXE/UEFI driver, we can update/modify DEPEX section of particular module and rebuild BIOS.